# Jquery find each element by attribute value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all labels with an attribute of "selected" without a null or empty value.  I can't seem to find any labels.  Here is the html.

```
<form id="frmPickGames">
    <div style="margin-top: 150px">
    <div data-bind="foreach: games, visible: games().length > 0">
        <div class="row clearRight borderBottom">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <label class="" data-bind="text: gameDate"></label> / Time:
                <label class="" data-bind="text: gameTimeET"></label> / Tv Station:
                <label class="" data-bind="text: tvStation"></label>
            </div>
            <div id="mode-group" class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center awayColumn">
                    <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $parent.save, attr: { id: gameId() + '~' + awayTeam(), selected: teamId() }">
                        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: gameId(), id: gameId() + '~' + awayTeam() }" selected >
                        <img data-bind="attr: { src: awayTeamLogoUrl, alt: awayTeamFullName }" style="height: 100px; width: 150px;" /><br />
                        <label data-bind="text: awayTeamFullName"></label>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center" style="padding-top: 50px;">AT</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center homeColumn">
                    <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $parent.save, attr: { id: gameId() + '~' + homeTeam() }">
                        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: gameId(), id: gameId() + '~' + homeTeam() } ">
                        <img data-bind="attr: { src: homeTeamLogoUrl, alt: homeTeamFullName }" style="height: 100px; width: 150px;" /><br />
                        <label data-bind="text: homeTeamFullName"></label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery that I'm trying to use to get all the labels so that I can set a class to show that the label was selected.  I'm assuming this doesn't work because the labels are too deep in the html code.

```
$('label[selected!=""]').each(function () {
    alert('hi');

});
```

Comment: Do you want the label or the radio button with selected? Because from your code, the label tags have selected inside the `data-bind` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna find the label that contains 'selected' in the 'data-bind'attribute, just use this selector:

```
$("label[data-bind*='selected']").each(function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: please see my edit, the alert is never being called.

Comment: Are you trying to get the labels that contains selected attr inside the `data-bind`? (Ex.: `<label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $parent.save, attr: { id: gameId() + '~' + awayTeam(), selected: teamId() }">`... Or are you trying to get elements with selected attribute like: `<input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: gameId(), id: gameId() + '~' + awayTeam() }" selected >`?

Comment: I'm trying to get (<label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $parent.save, attr: { id: gameId() + '~' + awayTeam(), selected: teamId() }"> )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like

```
$('label').each(function () {
    if($(this).find('input[selected]').size()){
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

to find all the labels that have an input that is 'selected'